# prevent datasource invocation on keypress of kendoui grid's filter

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid

i know that it is caused by the autocomple control in the header of a filtered grid (that tries to access the same datasource of the grid) 
The simplier way to prevent this beaviour seems to stop the keypress event.

I've tried the following:

```
$('TR.k-filter-row').find(".k-input").keypress(function (event) { 
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    //event.stopImmediatePropagation();   
    //event.preventDefault() 
});
```

i tried event.stopImmediatePropagation() and event.preventDefault()  as well, (and keypress, keyup, keydown events)but don't work .

i suspect that i'm not act on the right controls, but coloring the input controls (for debug pourpose) the selectors seem to point correctly to the right controls

```
$('TR.k-filter-row').find(".k-input").css({ "background-color": "red" });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the serverFiltering option of the AutoComplete. Here is how to do it:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.filterable.cell.template